# Loading different kinds of nodes in neo4j using LOAD CSV

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to use LOAD CSV and am having some challenges ...
I want to create different kinds of nodes based on the content of a particular column in my csv (TYPE)

Example:

```
ID,NAME,VALUE,LABEL,TYPE,KEY,GROUP,COLOR,SIZE,RECORDS,SCOPE
3,ERKRS_11CO,11CO,"Operating Concern 1122",ERKRS,ERKRS_11CO,EOI,#FF99CC,1,0,False
5,ERKRS_8500,8500,"IDES Australia and New Zealand",ERKRS,ERKRS_8500,EOI,#FF99CC,1,0,False
21,KKBER_1000,1000,"Credit control area Europe",KKBER,KKBER_1000,EOI,#336699,1,0,False
329,KOKRS_1111,1111,"1111 CONTROLLING AREA IN",KOKRS,KOKRS_1111,EOI,#CC99FF,1,0,False
330,KOKRS_1112,1112,"US COMPANY",KOKRS,KOKRS_1112,EOI,#CC99FF,1,0,False
```

I first tried:

```
// Build Nodes
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM 'file:///mynodesfile.csv' AS line
CREATE (line.NAME:line.TYPE :ee { name: line.LABEL , color: line.COLOR, records: TOINT(line.RECORDS), scope: line.SCOPE } ) ;
```

which did not work at all.  Then I tried

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM 'file:///mynodesfile.csv' AS line
WITH line
CASE line.TYPE
    WHEN 'ERKRS' THEN
        CREATE (e:ERKRS { ID: TOINT(line.ID) } )
    WHEN 'KKBER' THEN
        CREATE (e:KKBER { ID: TOINT(line.ID) } )    
    WHEN 'KOKRS' THEN
        CREATE (e:KOKRS { ID: TOINT(line.ID) } )    

SET e.name = line.LABEL 
    e.color = line.COLOR
    e.records = TOINT(line.RECORDS)
    e.scope = line.SCOPE )
;
```

Also not working....
Then I wrote a python program to generate the cypher clauses.  Because the actual file is much larger than the sample I gave, I tried to load it via the cypher shell with 
cat mynodes.cql | ./bin/cypher-shell.bat -u yourneo4juser -p yourpassword
(I'm using Windows, so I used power shell ....)

mynodes.cql first 4 records ....

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
CREATE (ROOT_EC3_800:ROOT:eoi { name: "Enterprise", records: 0, scope: "False"} )
CREATE (ERKRS_11CO:ERKRS:eoi { name: "Operating Concorn 1122", records: 0, scope: "False"} )
CREATE (ERKRS_8500:ERKRS:eoi { name: "IDES Australia and New Zealand", records: 0, scope: "False"} )
```

Invalid input 'C': expected whitespace, comment or LoadCSVQuery (line 2, column 1 (offset: 26))
"CREATE (ROOT_EC3_800:ROOT:eoi { name: "Enterprise", records: 0, scope: "False"} )"

Yet, entering 
CREATE (ROOT_EC3_800:ROOT:eoi { name: "Enterprise", records: 0, scope: "False"} ) at the neo4j browser, the node is created.

I am trying very hard to make this work.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` is only available for the `LOAD CSV` command, that's why you receive the error on your genereated script.

To respond to your first question, the problem is that in pure cypher, labels and relatonship types can't be dynamic. 
So if you want to create nodes with a dynamic label, you have to use APOC (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) with the procedure `apoc.create.node` like this :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM 'file:///mynodesfile.csv' AS line
CALL apoc.create.node([line.TYPE, 'eoi'], { name: line.LABEL , color: line.COLOR, records: TOINT(line.RECORDS), scope: line.SCOPE } ) ;
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you @logisima ! Really appreciate it :).  BTW, I added  'YIELD node RETURN node' and it worked great.